# term_exists() returning NULL on term that exists

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, terms

It seems that `term_exists()` is returning NULL for a term that already exists:

```
$name = "כל האזורים"
$taxonomy_name = "geographictermsisrael"
$args = array("slug" => "everything", "parent" => 0)

var_dump(term_exists($name, $taxonomy_name, $args)); // Returns NULL (not 0)

if ( !term_exists($name, $taxonomy_name, $args) ) {
    $foo = wp_insert_term($name, $taxonomy_name, $args);
    var_dump($foo); // Returns the array below
}

object(WP_Error)#4193 (2) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["term_exists"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(77) "השם או מזהה הכתובת כבר קיימים עם ההורה הזה."
    }
  }
  ["error_data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["term_exists"]=>
    string(3) "699"
  }
}
```

**If the term already exists, why might `term_exists()` return NULL?** This is what the database looks like:

```
mysql> select * from wp_term_taxonomy where taxonomy='geographictermsisrael';
+------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
| term_taxonomy_id | term_id | taxonomy              | description | parent | count |
+------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
|              738 |     699 | geographictermsisrael |             |      0 |     0 |
+------------------+---------+-----------------------+-------------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from wp_terms where term_id=699;
+---------+---------------------+------------+------------+
| term_id | name                | slug       | term_group |
+---------+---------------------+------------+------------+
|     699 | כל האזורים          | everything |          0 |
+---------+---------------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id=738;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument for [`term_exists()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists) is an integer, not an array.

> ### Parameters
>
> $term
>
> (*integer|string*) (*required*) The term
>   to check
>
> Default: *None*
>
> $taxonomy
>
> (*string*) (*optional*) The taxonomy name to
>   use
>
> Default: ''
>
> $parent
>
> (*integer*) (*optional*) $parent ID of parent
>   term under which to confine the exists search
>
> Default: 0

Pass the correct arguments and it works.

```
var_dump(term_exists($name, $taxonomy_name));
```

`0` is the default, so you don't need to specify it.